# How to fix expected primary-expression?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>

class test{

    public:
        void print()
        {
            std::cout<<"test print"<<std::endl;
        }

};

int main
{
    std::auto_ptr<test> t1 (new test);
    t1->print();

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting following error:

```
$g++ 5.cpp --std=c++11
5.cpp:16:22: error: expected primary-expression before ‘t1’
  std::auto_ptr<test> t1 (new test);
                      ^
5.cpp:16:22: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘t1’
5.cpp:16:22: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘t1’
5.cpp:17:2: error: ‘t1’ does not name a type
  t1->print();
  ^
5.cpp:19:2: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘return’
  return 0;
  ^
5.cpp:20:1: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
 }
 ^
```

Comment: [auto_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/auto_ptr/) is deprecated since `C++11`, please consider [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

Comment: dont use autoptr. unique_ptr is a better use case. Is this the real source code? is it possbile u forgot a ";" somewhere before?

Comment: Please make sure you can run a Hello World in C++ first before doing something more complicated.

Comment: oops, I forgot. and not looked at main function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is, that you forgot the parantheses in main.

```
int main { ...} // this is wrong!
```

but the right would be

```
int main() { ... }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int main // <-- Notice anything ?
```

Comment: @abc no one is safe from typos :) -- But do use `std::unique_ptr` instead of `std::auto_ptr`.

Comment: @abc ... and use `clang` as a linter plugin if your IDE supports it or as your main compiler; [even though the warning isnn't perfect it's much more clear](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bcfab49d9b4561c1).